# A Truncated CreateObject()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking, poco, t4

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738695.aspx) says:

> When working with the Entity Framework generated classes, consider
>   using the entity type's static CreateObjectName method to create a new
>   instance of an entity type. The Entity Data Model tools include this
>   method in each class when they generate the entity types. This create
>   method is used to create an instance of an object and set all the
>   properties of the class that cannot be null. **The method includes a
>   parameter for every property that has the Nullable="false"** attribute
>   applied in the CSDL file.

However, I'm using [T4 C# POCO Generator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) which evidently does not generate a Create *ObjectName* method for any entities.  I'm surprised.  Does anyone have a T4 template which *does* generate these methods to match what MSDN describes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are generated by default code generator and by ADO.NET EntityObject generator (T4 template). If you want it in T4 template for POCOs you must modify the template and write the code generation logic yourselves (or find it in EntityObjects' template).